# How to link main function with header file and create it's dll file?

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll

I am very beginner to work with dll and linking various file.

I just know write main() function and all other in same .c file and run it.

I have one program which works for pattern matching. It takes the string and check whether it exist in entire text string or not. like

Text string: my name is john

string to be matched: name

Answer: Yes

main function is like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char target[200];
    char *ch = target;
    char pattern[20];
    int i,k,count,l;
    printf("\nEnter the string: \n");
    fgets(target,100,stdin);
    printf("Enter the string to be matched: \n");
    fgets(pattern,20,stdin);
    l=strlen(pattern);
    i = kmp(target, strlen(target)-1, pattern, strlen(pattern)-1);
    //printf("I is : %d\n",i);
    if (i == -1)
        puts("False");
    else
        puts("True");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Which calls function kmp() and get result back. We can also print the result in kmp() function. kmp() function is as follow:

```
int kmp(char *target, int tsize, char *pattern, int psize)
{
    int i;
    int *pi = compute_prefix_function(pattern, psize);
    int k = -1;
    if (!pi)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0; i < tsize; i++) {

        while (k > -1 && pattern[k+1] != target[i])
            k = pi[k];
        if (target[i] == pattern[k+1])
            k++;
              if (k == psize - 1) {
            free(pi);
            return i-k;
        }
    }
    free(pi);
    return -1;
}
```

In kmp we call **compute_prefix_function(pattern, psize);** which is as below:

```
int *compute_prefix_function(char *pattern, int psize)
{
    int k = -1;
    int i = 1;
    int *pi = malloc(sizeof(int)*psize);
    if (!pi)
        return NULL;

    pi[0] = k;
    for (i = 1; i < psize; i++) {
        while (k > -1 && pattern[k+1] != pattern[i])
            k = pi[k];
        if (pattern[i] == pattern[k+1])
            k++;
        pi[i] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}
```

Header files need to be called:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

What I want to do is:

***Creating an implementations in a dll/shared library format. essentially, the dll should have a function extension which take a string and return a bool saying if the string exists or not.***

For that which function I need to put in .c file and header file and how to create .dll file for this?

I am using windows 7, VS 2010 and C programming.

Please explain me step by step.

Comment: Do I undestand correctly?  You wan the kmp() function to be in a DLL so you can call it from the main() program the same as it is now. But you want to have the kmp() code in a DLL and not in the main.c source?

Comment: Yes Nicholaz, you right. I want to know how to do that and how to create dll for that!

Answer (score 2):

I'll say more about the DLL further down, but for a start, here is the layout of the source files you'll need to do that.

You'll need three files:

- main.c
- kmp.h
- kmp.c.

Code structure:

File main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kmp.h"  // this will make the kmp() function known to main()

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char target[200];
   ... same code as you aready have

}
```

File kmp.h

```
// prototype to make kmp() function known to external programs (via #include)
extern int kmp(char *target, int tsize, char *pattern, int psize);
```

File kmp.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// declare kmp prototype as DLL-export
_declspec(dllexport) int kmp(char *target, int tsize, char *pattern, int psize);

// prototype for internal helper function
static int *compute_prefix_function(char *pattern, int psize); 


//
// implementation of kmp() function (and helper)
// 

int kmp(char *target, int tsize, char *pattern, int psize)
{
    int i;
    ... same program code as you aready have
}

int *compute_prefix_function(char *pattern, int psize)
{
    int k = -1;
    ... same program code as you aready have
}
```

.

Now, for a first step, you can make these three files, and compile them in your current project (i.e. split your current project source into those three files, just leave out the line in kmp where it says __declspec(dllexport) and compile as before (non-DLL) to see if all works).

.

You will then need to create a DLL project for kmp.h and kmp.c (that will compile a KMP.DLL and KMP.LIB).  Then you create a normal program (like your current sample) with main.c and need to link it with KMP.LIB / KMP.DLL

The following may be a bit fuzzy, because I only have VS2005 here, but the steps to create the DLL project should be essentially somewhat like this:

- new project: Type Win32 / Win32-Project
- name KMP
- in the wizard choose Type DLL and check "Empty Project"
- add your kmp.c and kmp.h files

In your main project (the one with the main.c program), you can then do

- File Menu > Add > Existing Project > KMP.vcproj

This will automatically build and link the DLL from with your main.c program project.

Comment: I added main.c file in same project an source file section. Now it gives error : d:\users\technoworld\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\temp3\temp3\main.c : fatal error C1853: 'Debug\temp3.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)

Here temp3 is project name.

Comment: In the Project-Properties->Configration-Properties->Compiler for your source files try to turn off "Uses Precompile-Header"

Comment: Edited the above text again (instructions for adding KMP project to main project).

Comment: I am using VS2010, in Configuration-propertes I did not find Compiler tab. It is showing three option General, Debugger and VC++ Dir under Configuration-propertes->.  I also checked other tabs but did not find it!

Comment: If you right-your .c files in the project tree and choose Properties, there will be more choices under Configuration-properties.  (I need to logoff now, good luck with the thing).

Comment: Program works fine now, project executed successfully, but How can I use dll file generated in main.cpp file? I dont know which sequence and how file should be executed.

Comment: Not sure, but this sounds like a new question you should ask with showing what you already did. Also up there in the other answer is a bit about it at the bottom: In your main project (the one with the main.c program), you can then do File Menu > Add > Existing Project > KMP.vcproj